# Tikz figure like an umbrella

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a multiplication technique called umbrella method. The following figure shows a demonstration of two digits by two digit multiplication like, `96 \times 47`. Can you help me to draw the following figure.

[image]

It will be better if the figure also consider three digit multiplications like `464 \times 123`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `[in=..., out=...]` to draw curved lines connecting two points.

Comment: @user202729 It's something about macro, not just a simple `[out=...,in=...]` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can probably done easier, but this might also work:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}

% helper macro to split a string in to a comma separated list
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makenumlist}[2]{%
    \def\splitnums##1##2\relax{%
        \edef#1{##1}%
        \@tfor\next:=##2\do{\edef#1{#1,\next}}%
    }%
    \splitnums#2\relax%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{umbrellatip}
\newcommand{\umbrellamultiply}[2]{%
    \makenumlist{\firstfactornum}{#1}%
    \makenumlist{\secondfactornum}{#2}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large]
        \setcounter{umbrellatip}{0}
        \foreach \n [count=\i] in \firstfactornum {
            \node (t\i) at (\i,0) {\n}; 
            \setcounter{umbrellatip}{\i}
        }
        \stepcounter{umbrellatip}
        \node (t\theumbrellatip) at (\theumbrellatip,0) {$\times$}; 
        \stepcounter{umbrellatip}
        \foreach \n [count=\i start from \theumbrellatip] in \secondfactornum {
            \node (t\i) at (\i,0) {\n}; 
            \setcounter{umbrellatip}{\i}
        }
        \foreach \t [count=\u start from 1] in {2,...,\theumbrellatip} {
            \draw (t\u.north) to[out=60, in=120] (t\t.north);
        }
        \draw (t1.north) to[out=60, in=120] coordinate (m) (t\theumbrellatip.north);
        \draw (m) -- (m |- 0,-20pt) arc (360:150:5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\umbrellamultiply{96}{47}

\umbrellamultiply{464}{123}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**Update:** Ribs added

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}

% helper macro to split a string in to a comma separated list
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makenumlist}[2]{%
    \def\splitnums##1##2\relax{%
        \edef#1{##1}%
        \@tfor\next:=##2\do{\edef#1{#1,\next}}%
    }%
    \splitnums#2\relax%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{umbrellatip}
\newcommand{\umbrellamultiply}[2]{%
    \makenumlist{\firstfactornum}{#1}%
    \makenumlist{\secondfactornum}{#2}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large]
        \setcounter{umbrellatip}{0}
        \foreach \n [count=\i] in \firstfactornum {
            \node (t\i) at (\i,0) {\n}; 
            \setcounter{umbrellatip}{\i}
        }
        \stepcounter{umbrellatip}
        \node (t\theumbrellatip) at (\theumbrellatip,0) {$\times$}; 
        \stepcounter{umbrellatip}
        \foreach \n [count=\i start from \theumbrellatip] in \secondfactornum {
            \node (t\i) at (\i,0) {\n}; 
            \setcounter{umbrellatip}{\i}
        }
        \foreach \t [count=\u start from 1] in {2,...,\theumbrellatip} {
            \draw (t\u.north) to[out=60, in=120] (t\t.north);
        }
        \draw (t1.north) to[out=60, in=120] coordinate (m) (t\theumbrellatip.north);
        \foreach \t [count=\v start from 2] in {3,...,\theumbrellatip} {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currenttip}{\v<(\theumbrellatip+1)/2 ? -1 : (\v>(\theumbrellatip+1)/2 ? 1 : 0)}
            \ifnum\currenttip>0\relax
                \draw (t\v.north) to[bend right] (m);
            \else
                \ifnum\currenttip<0\relax
                    \draw (t\v.north) to[bend left] (m);
                \fi
            \fi
        }
        \draw (m) -- (m |- 0,-20pt) arc (360:150:5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\umbrellamultiply{96}{47}

\umbrellamultiply{464}{13}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about the middle curve lines?

Comment: Yeah, they are missing, because I haven't found an easy way to draw them automatically =D

Comment: @topu Found a way ...

Comment: That's impressive. Thanks a lot. @JasperHabicht